# How to export a compiled C++ project as executable for Raspberry Pi 3 (ARM, Raspberry Pi OS 32 bit)

Tags: c++, gcc, raspberry-pi, gpio, wiringpi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B with Raspberry Pi OS x32.
I use Code::blocks and gcc-compiler for the development.
I wrote a simple C++ project that contains only one source file and use some libraries. The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <wiringPi.h>

using namespace std;

void switchOnLeds(int delay, int firstLed, int lastLed);
void digitalWrite(int pin, bool statement);
void simpleDelay(int cycles);
int calculateOperationTime();
bool lastStatement = false;
const int DELAY_PIN = 14;    //Pin only to delay    

int main()
{
    cout << "In this program I try to control the LED strip without SPI-wire. The LED strip must be connected with the Pin 11/GPIO 17. It is 6 pin on the left side from up. Pin 23/GPIO 11 must be free and not connected" << endl;
    int firstLed = 0;
    int lastLed = 0;
    wiringPiSetup () ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << "Enter first LED number: " << endl;
        cin >> firstLed;
        cout << "Enter second LED number: " << endl;
        cin >> lastLed;
        int delay = calculateOperationTime();
        cout << "Start to test with delta time: " << delay << "LEDs between " << firstLed << " and " << lastLed << " must be switched on" <<endl;
        switchOnLeds(delay, firstLed, lastLed);
    }
    return 0;
}

void switchOnLeds(int delay, int firstLed, int lastLed) {
    const auto BIT_0_HIGH_VOLTAGE_TIME = (250);    //nanoseconds to start transfer the logical 0 for ws2811 in fast mode
    const auto BIT_0_LOW_VOLTAGE_TIME = (1000);    //nanoseconds to end transfer the logical 0 for ws2811 in fast mode

    const auto BIT_1_HIGH_VOLTAGE_TIME = (600);    //nanoseconds to start transfer the logical 1 for ws2811 in fast mode
    const auto BIT_1_LOW_VOLTAGE_TIME = (650);     //nanoseconds to end transfer the logical 1 for ws2811 in fast mode

    const int CYCLES_0_HIGH = BIT_0_HIGH_VOLTAGE_TIME/delay;
    const int CYCLES_0_LOW = BIT_0_LOW_VOLTAGE_TIME/delay;

    const int CYCLES_1_HIGH = BIT_1_HIGH_VOLTAGE_TIME/delay;
    const int CYCLES_1_LOW = BIT_1_LOW_VOLTAGE_TIME/delay;

    const int BITS_FOR_SINGLE_LED = 24;         //how many bits contains a signal for a single LED
    const int PIN = 0;                          //Output pin
    const int LEDS = 10;


    pinMode (PIN, OUTPUT) ;
    auto programFinish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto programStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < LEDS; i++) {
        if (i >= firstLed && i <= lastLed) {
            for (int bit = 0; bit < BITS_FOR_SINGLE_LED; bit++) {
                digitalWrite(PIN, HIGH);
                simpleDelay(CYCLES_1_HIGH);
                digitalWrite(PIN, LOW);
                simpleDelay(CYCLES_1_LOW);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int bit = 0; bit < BITS_FOR_SINGLE_LED; bit++) {
                digitalWrite(PIN, HIGH);
                simpleDelay(CYCLES_0_HIGH);
                digitalWrite(PIN, LOW);
                simpleDelay(CYCLES_0_LOW);
            }
        }
    }
    programFinish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    long operationTime = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(programFinish - programStart).count())/(BITS_FOR_SINGLE_LED*LEDS) ;

    printf("Completed in ");
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(programFinish - programStart).count() << " ns but must be no longer as 300 000 nanoseconds on the Raspberry Pi 3b" << endl;
    std::cout <<"Operation must be 1250 nanoseconds nut it is: "<<operationTime << " nanoseconds" << endl;
}



void simpleDelay(int cycles){
    for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++){
        if (lastStatement == true){
            digitalWrite(DELAY_PIN, LOW);
            lastStatement = false;
        }
        else{
            digitalWrite(DELAY_PIN, HIGH);
            lastStatement = true;
        }
    }
}

int calculateOperationTime(){
    auto programEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const int steps = 10*24;
    auto programStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++ ){
        digitalWrite(DELAY_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(DELAY_PIN, LOW);
    }
    programEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    long deltaTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(programEnd - programStart).count();
    deltaTime/=(steps*2);
    return deltaTime;
}
```

I need to send this code to my customer for tests. He has a Raspberry Pi 3B with the same operating system. I can launch the compiled file from the release directory of the project using simple command in the terminal: sudo ./FileName .But when I try to launch this compiled file on a clear fresh installed Raspberry Pi OS 32 bit it can not be launched. The terminal says: sudo ./FileName: command not found. I need to install wiringPi and Code::blocks, compile the file from the IDE and after that I can launch the compiled file. How can I export the compiled file as executable for Raspberry Pi OS 32 bit (ARM-architecture)? How can I make executable in C++ for Linux ARM?

Comment: Does a clean install have a C++ environment and the library? C++ programs are not self-contained by default. You could experiment with a static build, but there's still no guarantee that there won't be dependencies. The simplest thing would be to document the dependencies required, and provide a build script. Better still, have your build script fetch the dependencies.

Comment: A proper C++ environment would still be required on the destination; it might not have been clear.

Comment: The clear Raspberry Pi OS image contains gcc-compiler. If I right understood the user can simple open the text editor nano, write a code, save the file with the extension: cpp and launch the compiler. The library WiringPi is not installed as default in the operating system.

Comment: It could also be the file compiled on the 4B uses a different interpreter, and that can't be found. Check to see what the executable expects with `file FileName` and see what comes up. Then compare that against a hello world compiled on the 3B.

Comment: @user4581301 you don't understood or didn't good read: I try to explain again: 1) I compile my code in a file, that runs perfect. 2) I save this file in a cloud 3)  I  format my SD card with the operating system for the Raspberry Pi 4B. 4) I install again the same operating system on the same SD card. 5) I plug the SD card in my Raspberry Pi 4B again 6) On the fresh OS I load the compiled file from the cloud and run it. It doesn't work. All this operations are made on the same Raspberry Pi 4B and the same official OS image

Comment: That I understood. I misread the question and thought the problem was only on the client side, RPi 3B.

Comment: `sudo ./Filename` outputting "command not found" could mean that either `sudo` is not found or that `Filename` does not exist. Which is it? This does not (yet) have anything to do with C++. And why are you running this command as root?

Comment: @Botje 1) sudo is found on every Linux distribution I have tested. I can delete sudo and try only: ./FileName. It is not important. 2) Filename exists - the trouble is in this two characters:  ./ (dot and slash). I'm new in C++ programming, I have only 5 years Java experience and can not understand what is that. 3) It is not important to call as root. When I wrote the same code on Java I had to launch the code only as root because the java virtual machine need to communicate with the GPIO and must have root-privilegies. I didn't find the info but I think C++ code needn't to be launched as root

Comment: If `Filename` exists in the current directory then `./Filename` should at least produce an error. Please edit your post with proof that `Filename` exists in the current directory and the exact error that calling `sudo ./Filename` produces. Also, fix the permissions of the GPIO device and/or add your user to the right group instead of using the bazooka that is sudo.

Comment: today when I try to launch the same file on the clear operating system I got the error: ./FileName: error while loading shared libraries: libwiringPi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. If I right understood the library libwiringPi.so was not added to the compiled file. How can I compile the code with the library for deployment?

Comment: You need to ship a copy of libwiringpi.so along with your program. Static linking (eg embedding it in your program) is only allowed if you satisfy the [requirements of the LGPL](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/blob/master/COPYING.LESSER)